# Calling elinks from shell script sometimes double fires

Tags: linux, shell

We have recently migrated from HPUX 11 to RHEL 6 and in the process our sysadmin group informed us that lynx was no longer available and we'd have to use elinks instead.  We make servlet calls from nightly batch processing scripts and never had a problem with lynx.  With elinks about half the time it double fires and calls the servlet twice (as much as two minutes between firings with no other activity on the system).

Being servlets each is independent and unaware of other instances and so we're having to do a lot of cleanup the following day and at times this results in very large financial transactions going screwy.

The sysadmins know nothing about elinks and have left it up to us, none of whom is a linux expert, to figure out why elinks sometimes double fires when called from a shell script and other times doesn't.  Anyone else experience something like this or have some sort of starting point?  I've of course been through the documentation and the elinks website.

Comment: What do you need that [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lwp-request) or any multitude of automatable HTTP clients can't provide?  And if you really need a browser at the console, why not [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I'm concerned that any other shell solution may result in the same multiple firing problem, but curl should have popped into my head early on, thanks for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just install lynx from a [RPM](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-i386/lynx-2.8.6-25.el6.i686.rpm.html) ?

Comment: We have no admin rights on the box and the sysadmins refuse.  lynx is dead, long live elinks.  Or something like that.

Comment: Install locally or compile from source then. If you have everything working with lynx there's no need to migrate.

Comment: Basic development tools aren't available on the server either, so can't compile from source.  That was my first attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

So there is actually a config option in elinks where it will retry three times if it doesn't get a response, and given that the servlet was a fire-and-forget it obviously didn't get a response.  I'm still a bit curious as to why it would only retry sometimes and not others, but curl is a better solution anyway so I'm moving on.  Thanks for the insights, all.